# template Parameter pack expansion on function call with array of data

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Trying to avoid overloading my function for x amount of parameters.

```
//T.. Types,C Class,R Return type
template<typename R = void,class C,typename T1,typename T2>
R callClassFunction(C& classname,void (C::*func)(T1,T2), void** myd)
{
    return (classname.*func)(*((T1*)myd[0]), *((T2*)myd[1]));
}
```

Would it be possible to do this with a variadic template?

I cant figure out the right syntax due to the data array.

Comment: Why do you need this function? And why are the arguments in that order? Can you just use `std::invoke()` instead?

Comment: Integration between multiple scripting environments and game engine. Each scripting engine stores data in different ways (string in lua, is not the same as string in JavaScript), they are expected to pass a void* array from copies converted from their memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
template <typename R, class C, typename... Ts, size_t... Is>
R impl(C& instance, R (C::*func)(Ts...), void** data, index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return (instance.*pmf)(*static_cast<Ts*>(data[Is])...);
}

template <typename R, class C, typename... Ts>
R callClassFunction(C& instance, R (C::*func)(Ts...), void** data)
{
    return impl(instance, func, data, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}
```

`index_sequence` is C++14 but can be implemented in C++11, you can find many implementations on SO.

The key is, we build up this sequence of integers ,and wecan use those to index into your `void*`. That sequence is the same size as `Ts`, so we can unpack `Ts` and `Is` together.

Note that this will only work for non-`const` pointers to member functions. You'll need to do this again for pointers to `const` member functions.

Also, if the member function takes a reference, this won't quite work - you'll need some slightly different manipulation. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: index_sequence Thats new.

Comment: Interesting, i think i'm forgetting something.
https://gyazo.com/ba9741d6b2997d77b422c6c235749d11

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to do this with a variadic template?

If I understand correctly what do you want, you're looking for something as follows

```
template<typename R, class C, typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
R callClassFunction (C & classname, R (C::*func)(Ts1...), Ts2 && ... as)
 { return (classname.*func)(std::forward<Ts2>(as)...); }
```

I mean:

1) the return type `R` can be deduced from the method pointer and there is no need to default it to `void`

2) the variadic list of arguments (`Ts1...`) can also be deduced from the method pointer

3) for the following parameter passed to `callClassFunction()`, thare are to be passed to `func()`, I suggest a different variadic list of types, `Ts2...`, because there is no need that `Ts1...` is equal to `Ts2...`; it's only needed that the `Ts2...` types are convertible to the `Ts1...` types; this way you can pass a `"123"` (a `char const *` or a `char[]`), and not necessarily a `std::string("123")`, to a method that wait a `std::string`

The following is a full working example

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo
 {
   long bar (std::string const & a, int b, char c)
    { return a.size() + b + c; }

   void baz (std::string const &, int, char)
    { }
 };

template<typename R, class C, typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
R callClassFunction (C & classname, R (C::*func)(Ts1...), Ts2 && ... as)
 { return (classname.*func)(std::forward<Ts2>(as)...); }

int main ()
 { 
   foo f;

   auto r { callClassFunction(f, &foo::bar, "123", 4, '5') };

   static_assert( std::is_same<long, decltype(r)>{}, "!" );

   callClassFunction(f, &foo::baz, "123", 4, '5');
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> What if i want to keep the `void*` array and use the `Ts1` types to do the casting from `void*`

I find it extremely dangerous but... if you define a template using as follows

```
template <typename T0, typename...>
using only_first = T0;
```

you can use it to impose in `callClassFunction()` a list of `void *` parameters long as `Ts1...` (renamed `Ts...` because there isn't `Ts2...` anymore)

```
template<typename R, class C, typename ... Ts>
R callClassFunction (C & classname, R (C::*func)(Ts...),
                     only_first<void *, Ts> ... as)
```

and, in the body of the function, you can use `Ts...` to cast the `void *` pointers to `Ts...` pointers

```
return (classname.*func)(*static_cast<Ts*>(as)...);
```

I repeat: I find it extremely dangerous and I'm scared thinking this solution.

But if you really want... the following is a modified full working example

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo
 {
   long bar (int a, double b, char c)
    { return a + b + c; }

   void baz (int, double, char)
    { }
 };

template <typename T0, typename...>
using only_first = T0;

template<typename R, class C, typename ... Ts>
R callClassFunction (C & classname, R (C::*func)(Ts...),
                     only_first<void *, Ts> ... as)
 { return (classname.*func)(*static_cast<Ts*>(as)...); }

int main ()
 { 
   foo f;

   int     i { 1 };
   double  d { 2.0 };
   char    c { '3' };

   auto r { callClassFunction(f, &foo::bar, (void*)&i, (void*)&d, (void*)&c) };

   static_assert( std::is_same<long, decltype(r)>{}, "!" );

   callClassFunction(f, &foo::baz, (void*)&i, (void*)&d, (void*)&c);
 }
```

Comment: Now, do I explicitly have to have the Ts2 template array? What if i want to keep the void* array and use the Ts1 types to do the casting from void*

Comment: @StevenVenham - are you sure you want something similar? I can't exclude that doesn't work but surely is a lot more complicated and dangerous. Say that your method (see `bar()`) receive a `std::string` and that you pass a `void *` corresponding to a `char[4]` (the `"123"` in my example); when you cast a pointer to `void`, formerly a pointer to a `char[4]`, to a pointer to a `std::string` and you dereference that casted pointer... well... I'm pretty sure that something wrong will happens.

Comment: I'm only implementing basic types. int, double,char*,char,float,ext. and a Explicit type check is implemented before the data types are even pulled from the hosts scripts VM. Unfortunately when working with script VM's alot of type safety goes right out the window....

Comment: @StevenVenham - I see... answer modified; hope this helps.